# Using jQuery Mobile in Tool for Cordova project targeted Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows 8.1 will resulted in layout not rendering properly

Tags: windows, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova

I am not sure if this is a known bug or some conflict with jQuery Mobile within the Tool for Cordova project but when I use jQuery Mobile inside mine project the layout did not rendered correctly.

For example, start with a blank project. I then added both jQuery 2.1.3 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 from NuGet. Then inside the index.html, I have added a text input element. It is pretty simple and nothing is complicated. Then trying to run the project on both simulators and real devices would yield the result that the text input element did not appear at all, even though it resided inside the DOM. Further investigation provided the same result like this question: [Tools for Apache Cordova: JQueryMobile wraps input tags inside a head tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866049/tools-for-apache-cordova-jquerymobile-wraps-input-tags-inside-a-head-tag). This did not happened when I targeted the app with Android or iOS. Everything would rendered correctly in those two platforms.

I suspect that there are some conflicts when Visual Studio built the application and injected WinJS as well as jQuery Mobile. I have searched a lot of place and there are no mentions of incompatibility between them.

After trying everything, I gone back to the basic. I started installing Cordova CLI and tested to see if this problem would be there. To my surprise, the Windows 8.1 and WP 8.1 projects from the Cordova CLI build are working perfectly fine. Everything is rendered correctly, although there was an issue with jQuery Mobile changePage().

If this is actually a bug in pre-released software, then I hope in the final release, everything should work correctly. In the meantime, anyone would like to try suggesting me a workaround for this problem. I know there are at least me and the other guy from the question that I have linked above that had issue like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update my finding: The problem is with the library winstore-jscompat.js. Apparently, even with the new CTP 3.1, the file is not the recent one from GitHub. I downloaded the new version from GitHub, replaced it with the old one, and everything works perfectly now.

The GitHub is from here: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat.